# Conditional statement not working in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I write this line of code it returns empty results. Same datatype, don't know why it isn't working in vscode.

```
    _df2 = _df[(_df.fa == 'TRUE') & (_df.fl == 'TRUE') & (_df.fg == 'FALSE')]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of `_df`. What is the output of `_df.head(10).to_dict('list')`?

Comment: Are you that that you have `'TRUE'`/`'FALSE'` strings in your columns?

Answer (score 0):

As @mozway suggested, try:

```
_df2 = _df[(_df.fa) & (_df.fl) & (~_df.fg)]
```

This will work if the values are boolean, i.e. True instead of 'TURE'